# PVstar + alternative for iPhone?

Tags: ios-appstore

PVstar+ was my favorite Android app. However I got an iphone and it's not even listed...

Are there alternatives to this for iPhone?

Comment: What do you mean "It's not listed" ? Android apps do not work on iOS. Only if a iOS version of the app was released - It could be found on the App Store.

Comment: You're right, What I meant is, it's not listed, is there another alternative? Thanks